# Kafka Producer batch size

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a question related to `batch.size` producer configuration.

What happens when `batch.size` has reached and the producer app thread sends more data?

Does the thread block till space becomes available in the buffer containing the batch?

Answer (score 6):

`batch.size` measures batch size in total bytes instead of the number of messages. It controls how many bytes of data to collect before sending messages to the Kafka broker. Set this as high as possible, without exceeding available memory. The default value is 16384.

When you use `Producer.send()`, you fill up buffers on the producer. When a buffer is full, the producer sends the buffer to the Kafka broker and begins to refill the buffer.