# Does anyone knows kafka producer hanging fix

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka

Can anyone please tell me about this exception.

```
ERROR [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-2] c.o.p.a.s.CalculatorAdapter [CalculatorAdapter.java:285] 
Cannot send outgoingDto with decision id = 46d1-9491-123ce9c7a916 in kafka: 
org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaProducerException: Failed to send; 
nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: 
Expiring 1 record(s) for save-request-0:604351 ms has passed since batch creation
  at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.lambda$buildCallback$4(KafkaTemplate.java:602)
  at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory$CloseSafeProducer$1.onCompletion(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.java:871)
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer$InterceptorCallback.onCompletion(KafkaProducer.java:1356)
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ProducerBatch.completeFutureAndFireCallbacks(ProducerBatch.java:231)
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ProducerBatch.done(ProducerBatch.java:197)
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.failBatch(Sender.java:676)
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.sendProducerData(Sender.java:380)
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.runOnce(Sender.java:323)
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:239)
  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: 
Expiring 1 record(s) for save-request-0:604351 ms has passed since batch creation
```

I have been fighting with him for the second week.
Revised a bunch of fix recipes, but none of the recipes helped.
My program sends messages about 60 kilobytes in size, but they do not reach the kafka server.
The entire java application log is filled with exceptions of this kind.

Comment: Have you tried to reduce the `batch.size` to 60KB?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the time to fill the batch size takes longer than the time of the transaction, so the message is not sent.

```java
// example
Properties props = new Properties();
...

pros.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, 60000); // 60kb
...

Producer producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);
```

Checkout this articles.

- Kafka Producer Batch

  - [Kafka Producer batch size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65419339/kafka-producer-batch-size)
- Batch size configuration

  - http://cloudurable.com/blog/kafka-tutorial-kafka-producer-advanced-java-examples/index.html
  - https://kafka.apache.org/26/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/ProducerConfig.html

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.